# bootstrapping ansible prerequisites with the script module. python required?

Tags: ansible

Goal: Given a Debian server without python installed (and a few other missing ansible prerequisites), use ansible to get them installed so I can then use the normal ansible modules (almost all of which require python) to provision the server.

According to [the ansible documentation for the "script" module](http://docs.ansible.com/script_module.html), "This module does not require python on the remote system, much like the raw module.". However, based on my tests, it seems like the script module **does in fact attempt to run python on the remote system**, at least if the `sudo` option is true. I believe I can get this to work with the script module as long as I don't enable ansible's `sudo` option, but then I need my remote user to have sudo permission without a password prompt or my script is just going to hang waiting for interactive entry of the sudo password.

So my question is: A) What's the deal with the "script" module. Does it require python on the remote system or not?

and B) Is there a better way to achieve my larger goal which is fully automated deployment without any manual steps before ansible itself can be used?

Here's my output of `ansible-playbook -vvv` which shows clear it is running `/usr/bin/python` on the remote system, and there is no file there because python is not yet installed.

```
TASK: [install ansible prerequisites]
*****************************************  <10.9.8.31> ESTABLISH
CONNECTION FOR USER: plyons <10.9.8.31> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt',
'-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s',
'-o', 'ControlPath=/Users/plyons/.ansible/cp/ansible-
ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o',
'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications
=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o',
'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10',
'10.9.8.31', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-
tmp-1396233547.35-182235573044157 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp
/ansible-tmp-1396233547.35-182235573044157 && echo
$HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1396233547.35-182235573044157'"]
<10.9.8.31> PUT
/var/folders/n4/8skjkv9s5hbc4t5r0tr0xrk80000gn/T/tmpT1Vh6e TO
/home/plyons/.ansible/tmp/ansible-
tmp-1396233547.35-182235573044157/stat <10.9.8.31> EXEC ['ssh',
'-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o',
'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/Users/plyons/.ansible/cp
/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o',
'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications
=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o',
'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10',
'10.9.8.31', '/bin/sh -c \'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via
ansible, key=hyplatqjmvybpfqtukjegkibbuyrnoqj] password: " -u root
/bin/sh -c \'"\'"\'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-
hyplatqjmvybpfqtukjegkibbuyrnoqj; /usr/bin/python
/home/plyons/.ansible/tmp/ansible-
tmp-1396233547.35-182235573044157/stat\'"\'"\'\'']
```

Here's my playbook task:

```
tasks:
  -
    name: install ansible prerequisites
    script: ansible_prereqs.sh creates=/root/.ansible_prereqs_installed
```

And that ansible_prereqs.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#install ansible prereqs manually or all apt-based ansible commands will fail
# http://euphonious-intuition.com/2013/01/bootstrapping-a-cluster-with-ansible-debian-6-and-oracle-java-7/
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python python-apt python-pycurl sshpass
touch /root/.ansible_prereqs_installed
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

raw and scripts dont require python. I think the creates require python. To verify you  can run

```
ansible -m script -a "ansible_prereqs.sh" 10.9.8.31 -vvvv
```

what you can do is shift the creates function to your script

```
#!/bin/sh
#install ansible prereqs manually or all apt-based ansible commands will fail
# http://euphonious-intuition.com/2013/01/bootstrapping-a-cluster-with-ansible-debian-6-and-oracle-java-7/
if [ ! -f /root/.ansible_prereqs_installed ]; then
        apt-get update
        apt-get install -y python python-apt python-pycurl sshpass
        touch /root/.ansible_prereqs_installed
        echo "CHANGE"
fi
```

And you can have your playbook something like this

```
tasks:
  -
    name: install ansible prerequisites
    script: ansible_prereqs.sh creates=/root/.ansible_prereqs_installed
    register: ans_preq
    changed_when: "'CHANGE' in ans_preq.stdout"
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This helps. The `changed_when` line seems to be invalid YAML and ansible is showing a syntax error about the quotes.

Comment: Register was missing a colon and this made the changed_when look like the problem--fixed now.

Answer (score 10):

OK, further testing leads me to understand that @DomaNitro is correct in that it's not the `script` module itself per-say that requires python, but the `creates` option in particular, because that uses a `stat` python script.

However, things still seem to work fine because in the initial check for the `creates` marker file, ansible will do: `/usr/bin/python /home/plyons/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1396271950.37-134911276396535/stat`, which will fail because `/usr/bin/python` is not present, but that's fine because we want the script to run anyway.

Once my `ansible_prereqs.sh` script runs, ansible's `stat` module will start working because `/usr/bin/python` is now installed, so subsequent reruns will see the marker file exists and bypass the script.

So I don't need to implement the `creates` logic in my shell script code. Here's my final working playbook:

```
---
-
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    -
      name: install ansible prerequisites
      script: ansible_prereqs.sh creates=/root/.ansible_prereqs_installed
```

And here's the script it runs `ansible_prereqs.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
apt-get -qq update
apt-get -qq --yes install python python-apt python-pycurl sshpass
touch /root/.ansible_prereqs_installed
```

Here's some `ansible-playbook -vvv` output with explanatory comments added.

```
<10.9.8.31> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: plyons

#Not sure exactly what this does, but presumably some basic
#bootstrap sanity checking
<10.9.8.31> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt',
'-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o',
'ControlPath=/Users/plyons/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o',
'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no',
'-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-
keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o',
'ConnectTimeout=10', '10.9.8.31', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p
$HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1396273094.39-170062058638174 && chmod
a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1396273094.39-170062058638174 &&
echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1396273094.39-170062058638174'"]

#OK the "creates" option causes ansible to upload the "stat"
#python program
<10.9.8.31> PUT
/var/folders/n4/8skjkv9s5hbc4t5r0tr0xrk80000gn/T/tmp5CVz6i TO
/home/plyons/.ansible/tmp/ansible-
tmp-1396273094.39-170062058638174/stat

#Then ansible attempts to run it with /usr/bin/python
#This fails but ansible seems to proceed anyway, which is OK
<10.9.8.31> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o',
'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/Users/plyons/.ansible/cp
/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o',
'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications
=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o',
'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '10.9.8.31',
'/bin/sh -c \'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible,
key=llljvkxiztigvqonzohgzwwekusxtprk] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c
\'"\'"\'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-llljvkxiztigvqonzohgzwwekusxtprk;
/usr/bin/python /home/plyons/.ansible/tmp/ansible-
tmp-1396273094.39-170062058638174/stat\'"\'"\'\'']

#Now ansible uploads my script
<10.9.8.31> PUT
/Users/plyons/projects/redacted/deploy/ansible_prereqs.sh
TO /home/plyons/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1396273094.39-170062058638174/ansible_prereqs.sh

#Then it marks it executable
<10.9.8.31> EXEC ['ssh', '-C',
'-tt', '-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s',
'-o', 'ControlPath=/Users/plyons/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r',
'-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o',
'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications
=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o',
'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '10.9.8.31',
u'/bin/sh -c \'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible,
key=cgmwlvtjoxuighdqujwmmpvioiumveac] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c
\'"\'"\'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-cgmwlvtjoxuighdqujwmmpvioiumveac; chmod +rx
/home/plyons/.ansible/tmp/ansible-
tmp-1396273094.39-170062058638174/ansible_prereqs.sh\'"\'"\'\'']

#Then it runs it
<10.9.8.31> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-q', '-o',
'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o',
'ControlPath=/Users/plyons/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o',
'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no',
'-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-
keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o',
'ConnectTimeout=10', '10.9.8.31', u'/bin/sh -c \'sudo -k && sudo -H -S
-p "[sudo via ansible, key=cqqswbszbeabpclraxsxwzzatbolgmgf] password:
" -u root $SHELL -c \'"\'"\'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-
cqqswbszbeabpclraxsxwzzatbolgmgf; /home/plyons/.ansible/tmp/ansible-
tmp-1396273094.39-170062058638174/ansible_prereqs.sh \'"\'"\'\'']

#Then it deletes it
<10.9.8.31> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt',
'-q', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o',
'ControlPath=/Users/plyons/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o',
'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no',
'-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-
keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o',
'ConnectTimeout=10', '10.9.8.31', "/bin/sh -c 'rm -rf
/home/plyons/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1396273094.39-170062058638174/
>/dev/null 2>&1'"]
```

Comment: thanks for this last post. Now I know what to do tomorrow ;-)